# How to add an onclick event in html for Javascript - by a non programmer

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

This is my first post and I'm asking for help. I am not a programmer of any kind but keen to understand programming and have set up a [Codepen page](https://codepen.io/3DAttic/full/gOrrQzq) as an example. I am trying to share with some people who have asked can the page allow mouse clicks to work?

What I'm trying to get is to have this working without a keyboard click event, i.e. `onkeydown=` or `onkeyup=`, which is what happens now but work with a mouse click which will allow this to work from a mobile phone browser?

If someone can write/show the code I need, I would be very grateful. I see that the HTML needs to define the `onclick` event and then do two things, the first is `speakPrevious` and the second `getNewRandomColor`. I would think that JavaScript will need to define the `onclick` element? But I am not sure...

```
  `HTML`
  <body onkeydown="speakPrevious()">
  <body onkeyup="getNewRandomColor()">
  

  `JS`
  speakPrevious();
  function speakPrevious() {
     var synth = window.speechSynthesis;
     var utterThis = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(window.value);
     synth.speak(utterThis);
  }

    getNewRandomColor();
    function getNewRandomColor() {
    var myArray = ['Red','Green', 'Blue',  'Yellow', ];
    var rand = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];     

    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor = rand;
    var oldRand = rand;
    window.value = oldRand;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can allow users to interact with the web page by either using their keyboard or by clicking on the page if you use an event listener.
In your javascript you can add code (like below) which will trigger the function code whenever the html body element is clicked. This will add functionality to allow users to click on the page.

```
const page = document.querySelector("body");
    page.addEventListener("click", function () {
        speakPrevious();
        getNewRandomColor();
    });
```

Additionally you may find it easier  to combine your body tag events into one body tag with both events.

```
<body onkeydown="speakPrevious()" onkeyup="getNewRandomColor()">
```

This will allow the user to either click on the page to trigger the functions or to use a keyboard event.

My final document code looked like this

```
<html>
<body onkeydown="speakPrevious()" onkeyup="getNewRandomColor()">
    <p>The algorithm will select colors at random from RGBY and you may see the same color several times in a row. This
        is expected behavior and NOT a fault.<br>Click inside the color and press any keyboard key to move to the next
        color.</p>
</body>
<script>
    const page = document.querySelector("body");
    page.addEventListener("click", function () {
        speakPrevious();
        getNewRandomColor();
    });

    function speakPrevious() {
        var synth = window.speechSynthesis;
        var utterThis = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(window.value);
        synth.speak(utterThis);
    }

    function getNewRandomColor() {
        var myArray = ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Yellow', ];
        var rand = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];

        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor = rand;
        var oldRand = rand;
        window.value = oldRand;
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Patadam, that code has been added and works. A quick follow up question the code works when you touch the text, can this be changed to work by touching anywhere on the screen?

Comment: I'm currently unable to replicate the problem, for all my attempts across both mobile and desktop the application works when the user clicks anywhere on the page. I've attached to my answer my full final HTML & Javascript so you can compare. Hopefully, this helps.

Comment: thank you Patadam, on my Mac, it works via keyboard to change color and speak BUT when i use the touch pad i have to have the cursor around the text at the top. Thank you for trying . I was curious to see if it could be changed at all.